# mp3 playback failed when moved to a class

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

I've problem with playing music in my app. 
If I write this in viewcontroller viewDidLoad, everything works.

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/jingle.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);
else
    [audioPlayer play];
```

But when I put it to my own class, instantiate it in the same viewController in viewDidLoad and call method with exactly the same code, it doesn't work. Please why?

Comment: Are you instantiating the class and calling the method from viewDidLoad or are you making the call from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm creating instance from viewDidLoad.
 AmbientSounds *as = [[AmbientSounds alloc]init];
 [as playSound];

In playSound is copy/paste of code I write above :/

Comment: Try logging "as" to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: Just tried: AS <AmbientSounds: 0x1e0147b0>

Comment: maybe there's problem with path? But why it works directly from viewController? doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because your instance is being deallocated after the viewDidLoad method goes out of scope. Make a property, typed strong, for as, and see if that works.